# Regarding Hadoop cluster mode

Tags: hadoop

I have a 2 node Hadoop cluster. One is master and the other is the slave. I had uploaded a CSV file of size 174 MB from my slave machine to HDFS.

Then I ran the MR job from slave itself. MR job finished within 5 minutes. If I run the same MR job from master it is taking nearly 20 minutes. I had kept the blocksize to 30MB in both master and slave.

Can u please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Interesting.. How are you running MR job from slave?

Comment: I had clustered the hadoop and in my slave nodemanager and datanode are running.I had used this command to run the MR job          bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/Divya/network-analytics-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar client_traffic_upload /user/netlog/upload/20120708-0000-0030.csv /user/divya/out

Comment: Isn't that you are invoking it through master?

Comment: No from slave I had run that command.It is taking less time to finish MR job.The same command I had run on the master also.But it is taking more time.I'm able to run MR jobs from both the machines

Comment: did you check network latency accross your machines?

Comment: No.This problem is only because of network latency?

Comment: Does this problem occurs only due to latency (or) due to some other issues.can u explain please